# I'm a Canadian citizen and now a US resident. How do I close my Canadian RRSP and TFSA?

Tags: taxes, canada, irs, rrsp, tfsa

I am a Canadian citizen who moved to the US in 2009. I am now a US resident and Canadian non-resident. I still have a Canadian RRSP, TFSA, and bank account. I've filed FBARs since becoming a US resident.  I would like to close the RRSP and TFSA and eventually move all the funds to the US, but I am clueless about the financial or tax implications of doing this in either the US or Canada. How should I proceed, and what do I need to do to remain in tax compliance? The cross-border tax consultants I have found are prohibitively expensive.

Comment: https://www.moneysense.ca/columns/ask-a-planner/what-to-do-with-your-canadian-investments-when-moving-to-the-u-s/ might be helpful, starting about half way down with "TFSAs remain tax-free for Canadian tax purposes..."

Comment: Realize that as a non-resident of Canada, you will pay so-called Part XIII tax of 25% to the Canadian federal government on the RRSP as it is cashed out (the article mentioned by @Canuck says 15% for certain withdrawals).  The IRS does not recognize the tax free status of either the TFSA or the RRSP.  The tax consultants are probably worth their money, unless you do your research carefully.